# How to debug step into only my own C++ code in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-debugging

I am debugging C++ code using Visual Studio 2019. I want to step through - and into - my dode using only F11.

Often, though, when objects are contructed and passed as parameters e.g

```
DoSomething( LINE_INFO() );
```

F11 steps into the contuctor of LINE_INFO, so that I am at

```
namespace Microsoft{ namespace VisualStudio {namespace CppUnitTestFramework
{
    // __LineInfo
    struct __LineInfo
    {
        __LineInfo(const wchar_t* pszFileName, const char* pszFuncName, int lineNumber)
            :pszFile(pszFileName),
            pszFunc(reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(pszFuncName)),
            line(lineNumber)
        {   
        }
        
        const wchar_t* pszFile;
        const unsigned char* pszFunc;
        int line;
    };
```

Now, I ***could*** just hit Shift+F11 (Step out), or - in this case - 2 @ F10 or F11, ***BUT*** this is a simplisitc example, and there are sometimes multiple constructed paremeters, some of which call multiple base constructors), and I don't want to have to do that for each such parameter.

Is there a way, using Visual Studio (not VS code), to step into only my code and treat "step into" MS & other library code as "step over"?